# Is that good approach to embed OTP (one time password) algorithm into Enterprise mobile apps to support offline capability?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, two-factor-authentication

**UPDATED:** We are building Mobile apps on Windows, IOS & Android platform to generate OTP (one time password) for a regulated system. The system will prompt challenge phrase when user attempt to login and the displayed challenge need to be keyed into mobile App to generate the OTP. The generated OTP is then entered back into System to successfully login.

So far the requirements for mobile OTP generate app is good as we can expose a service to generate OTP with required security.

But, we have a wired requirement to support the same feature with offline capability where mobile has no internet connectivity. The only choice we know is to embed the OTP algorithm & key into app and apply suitable security mechanism. Algorithm is custom built propitiatory algorithm and without compromising security we need to achieve the offline capability. Is that a good approach to embed algorithm & key into app to enable offline capability? What is the recommended solution.

Comment: How would you implement the two-factor *without* the algorithm on the phone? SMS?

Comment: Enterprise will expose API

Comment: Just a side note: I may be wrong, but to me it seems that you may need to get a more thorough understanding of security mechanisms before trying to actually implement any security-related software.

Comment: @HannoBinder Thanks for your response. I've updated my question to give more clarity.

Comment: That really improved the question. The answer is still the same: Yes, implement the algorithm in the app. If the algorithm is such that an attacker could compromise your security just by extracting the algo from the app, then the algorithm was not suited for security in the first place. The shared secret ("key") should probably *not* be embedded in the app. It should be randomly generated when the app is configured after installation and then stored at some app-private location on the device. Have a look at Goggle's Authenticator to see how the mechanism can be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean by "Enterprise will expose API".

But, you *will* need something tied to the physical phone device, like the SIM module (i.e. the phone number) or an app with secure/private storage for two-factor to work.

An API exposed on the internet, without a strong link to the authentication token (phone), is *not* secure.

So, I guess the only answer is: Yes, you should implement the "OTP algorithm" in the app. The app must store the shared secret in a private storage that is not (easily) accessible to other apps. Then, depending on the kind of OTP, you need to provide some means of synchronization between the app and the server. For Google's Authenticator this is just establishing a common timebase because the "OTP" is not strictly one-time but changes (only) depending on the current date+time; hence the current time becomes the "challenge" the server implicitly poses for the client to return the correct response. The good thing is that you don't need access to the internet to know the current time in your app. You only need to synchronize the timebase now and then to make sure the clock in your app does not differ too much from the server's.

The server could instead also send an explicit challenge, like a sequential number. This challenge would be displayed to the user attempting to log-in, the user would have to type the number into the app and return the app's answer to the server.

Many more options are available, but the bottom line is: To provide reasonable security, the OTP *must* be calculated on the phone.